# Auto-commit changes to TRUE after a while using a connection pool

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling

I got some strange problem.

I use a Pool to create and manage DB Connections, I set the `DefaultAutocommit` option to `FALSE`.

But after a while, when an error occur and a `rollback` is called an Exception is thrown : `Can't call rollback when autocommit=true`

Relaunching JBoss will solve the problem as a new DataSource will be created.

Here is how I create my Datasource :

```
protected DataSource getDataSource(String driverClassName, String dbUrl, String dbUser, String dbPwd) {
    PoolProperties poolProperties = new PoolProperties();
    poolProperties.setUrl(dbUrl);
    poolProperties.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    poolProperties.setUsername(dbUser);
    poolProperties.setPassword(dbPwd);

    poolProperties.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);
    poolProperties.setTestWhileIdle(false);
    poolProperties.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    poolProperties.setDefaultTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
    poolProperties.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    poolProperties.setTestOnReturn(false);
    poolProperties.setLogAbandoned(false);
    poolProperties.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    poolProperties.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(20);
    poolProperties.setMaxActive(100);
    poolProperties.setInitialSize(10);
    poolProperties.setJdbcInterceptors("org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");

    return new DataSource(poolProperties);
}
```

And how I get the connections :

```
xxx.getDataSource().getConnection();
```

I didn't try yet but my first call will be to force the autocommit directly on the connection using `setAutoCommit(false)`.

Though I don't understand why the `poolProperties.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);` is stopping doing the job.

Stack trace :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Can't call rollback when autocommit=true
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:929)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4805)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor302.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:125)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState.invoke(ConnectionState.java:140)
    at $Proxy333.rollback(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you provide error stack trace ?

Comment: Most likely it is a bug in either the connection pool or the MySQL JDBC driver. Other than that, I think this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Well I didn't find any trace of such a bug. But we'll try to force the attribute on the connection directly. It may helps other if that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is what is in place today, I force the `AutoCommit` attribute on each connection created by the pool.

This works, so it definitely may be a bug of the pool classes.

Edit:
I also had a problem with transaction isolation that was set the same way but not taken into account. After some research I found that this could be related to the Mysql connector/J I use (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) .

I found this interesting parameter in the doc :

**useLocalSessionState**

> Should the driver refer to the internal values of autocommit and
>   transaction isolation that are set by Connection.setAutoCommit() and
>   Connection.setTransactionIsolation() and transaction state as
>   maintained by the protocol, rather than querying the database or
>   blindly sending commands to the database for commit() or rollback()
>   method calls?

**Default value :** false